# I want to make a small co-op 3D RPG. Where do I begin?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know how to program although I haven't done much in C# yet. But I understand every code snippet I read. I mostly script at my job. I have little to no experience in graphical design or animations.

The only thing I have done so far in Unity 3D is the ball rolling tutorial.
I have some questions though as I have a hard time understanding where I should begin. I know co-op 3D RPG is a project with a HUGE scope, but this is what I would like to accomplish to begin with:

- Mini world (half the size of a WoW zone)
- Populate world with terrain, trees and some buildings. Maybe a cave.
- Have a playable character that can move around and interact with some objects.

Could anyone guide me into the right direction? What documentation should I read? Are there any RPG packs or plugins that can help me achieve this? Any nice tutorials you know of?

If 3D is too complicated to start with, I'm also willing to try an isometric game.

PS: Are there any free (or reasonably priced) HD asset packs that include animations? Or will I have to provide those myself as well?

Answer (score 0):

Co-Op RPG's are quite large;  Infact most people have tools that would help this speed up production;  Although you're asking where to start.  Most of my programming knowledge comes from theory and pretty basic knowledge;  But I have an idea on where you should start!

A big factor on Co-Op is well.... Of-course CO-OP so something you should play around with first is data and how it's stored but even though you have knowledge of this factor Unity has a good way of storing it from Host to Client!

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetStateSync.html?_ga=2.98238303.1333003911.1509902124-1740889112.1506544791

Another factor of -Co-Op is the dynamic spawning that is going to be pretty heavy although their are quite a few ways of doing this I'm sure their are plenty of correct as-well as incorrect ways of doing it!

Personally I would develop a database and call-Events with SQLite though this would be a heavy and complex job to do correctly and efficiently
but unity3d has UNetCustomSpawning documentation that seems to work pretty well for it's inteded use although it takes some heavy tinkering to get right so I would suggest once you get synchronization done you should check out some Spawning

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetCustomSpawning.html

With Every Co-Op Action it must be handled and heres how!

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html

How about the actual connection?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetDiscovery.html

Although reading alot of this may help;  I would suggest rading through this and giving it a shot.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSetup.html

and if you find no help or it's doing you some trouble

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/tanks-tutorial

You may hear about "Tanks",  alot though I personally am quite stubborn so I couldn't bear to look into it untill I did just earlier this month;  It shows a correct way of doing things from Shooting,  to spawning,  and may other things.

I am un-certain this is a good or bad answer for you as this I believe is quite a personal question but as their are about a thousand and a thousand more ways of doing this I think what I have shown is a great way of starting just to get an idea of how the ball should start rolling!

-Thanks!